# UpperCamelCase convention after object conversion

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.1

I have the following object with values returned as result a from RxJs subscribe method:

```
result: any
{
    message: null
    role: Object
    success: true
}
```

And I convert it to `MyResponse` type in TypeScript:

```
export class BaseResponse {

        public Message: string = null;

        public Success: boolean = null;

    }

export class MyResponse extends BaseResponse {

        public Role: Role = new Role();

    }
..
getModel() {
    this.roleService.get(this.id).subscribe(
        result => {
            let getResponse: MyResponse = <MyResponse>result;
            console.log(getResponse.Role.ApplicationId); // <-- null reference error
        },
        error => { },
        () => {
        }
    );
}
```

The problem is that looking at `getResponse` object in Chrome debugger, the objects' properties' first letters are lowercase. Shouldn't it be uppercase? Can I make it uppercase?

```
getResponse
{
    role: Object, 
    message: null, 
    success: true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<>` operator is **not** a type cast, because TypeScript "is not present" at runtime any more. Only at compile time. It is *type assertion*.

So

```
let getResponse: MyResponse = <MyResponse>result;
```

does **not** change the value. It will only tell the compiler that it should infer the `MyResponse` type. So if the response from the server has uppercased properties, they still will be uppercased at runtime. If you want them to be lowercased you need to apply a transform function.

You can read more about type assertion here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

---

*EDIT: You updated your question, I'll add some more info below.*

Even though you defined `MyResponse` as a `class`, TypeScript will not use it as such in your code (when setting `getResponse`). TypeScript will use the class as an interface. Thus, `public Role: Role = new Role();` is not executed. If you want to initialize this property you have to create a new instance, e.g. `new MyResponse()`.

> Shouldn't it be uppercase? Can I make it uppercase?

In JavaScript land object properties are usually lowercased. But working with some C# backend I got used to have uppercased properties, too ;) So it's your decision.

Comment: Thank you. My problem indeed was with the new JSON serializer in ASP.NET Core MVC, I've changed the naming behaviour back to upper camel case: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194